# sql server trigger syntax

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I am doing an update on a table and need to get both the value of a field before the update and the value of the field after the update.  I am getting the value before the update from the deleted table and the value after the update from the inserted table (see below).  Is this the correct way to do this ?

```
insert into [log].[userPoints] 
(accountId,oldPoints,newPoints)
SELECT del.accountId, del.points, i.points
FROM [user].[Points] AS p
INNER JOIN deleted AS del ON del.accountId = p.accountId
inner join inserted as i on i.accountId = p.accountId
```

Comment: This looks correct. Have yo tested?

Comment: Not yet, just wanted to confirm it is OK to do joins to both the deleted and inserted tables in the same SQL statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, entirely correct. You can access both tables in the same SQL statement, and your joins look good.